# How to fix "undefined method `as_png'" for rqrcode gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

I'm getting this error when I try to use the [rqrcode](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode) gem to turn a QR code into a PNG file:

```
undefined method `as_png' for #<RQRCodeCore::QRCode:0x00007f90b42ec330>
```

Here is the code:

```
self.secure_hex = SecureRandom.hex
    self.qr_code = RQRCodeCore::QRCode.new("https://app.mapviapp.com/check_ins/new?d=#{self.secure_hex}")
    self.qr_code_image = RQRCodeCore::QRCode.new("https://app.mapviapp.com/check_ins/new?d=#{self.secure_hex}").as_png
```

and the [API documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rqrcode#as-png).

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that gem, but the API docs you linked are for `RQRCode::QRCode`, and you're initializing a `RQRCodeCore::QRCode`

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're initializing `RGRCodeCore::QRCode` instead of `RQRCode::QRCode` as dinjas pointed out. Try changing it this way as the documentation suggests to do:

```
require 'rqrcode'
self.secure_hex = SecureRandom.hex
self.qr_code = RQRCode::QRCode.new("https://app.mapviapp.com/check_ins/new?d=#{self.secure_hex}")
self.qr_code_image = RQRCode::QRCode.new("https://app.mapviapp.com/check_ins/new?d=#{self.secure_hex}").as_png
```

Also, in the code you shared, you create an instance of `self.qr_code`, which contains the exact string as the `self.qr_code_image` instance. Are you sure you need that?

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: @JacksonRiso I'm glad! Accepted answer? :)